# Oauth2 with swift

Tags: ios, swift, laravel, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to integrate oauth2 to my project. I have my own api service which written in laravel framework. And I do have oauth2 service as well.

And I have looked some of the tutorials about oauth2 implementation. But I have a question. I have a login function here ;

```
func login(){
    let url = "http://someurl/oauth/token"
    let paramater: [String : Any] = ["grant_type": "password",
                     "client_id": someid,
                     "client_secret": "somesecret",
                     "username" : "username",
                     "password" : "1234567",
                     "scope" : ""
                     ]
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: paramater, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response)
        if let dict = response.result.value as? [String:Any]{
            if let accessToken = dict["access_token"] as? String{
                self.oauth(token: accessToken)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I run this function, I take access token and execute this function.

```
  func oauth(token : String){
    let url = "http://someurl/api/user"
    let header = ["Accept" : "application/json",
                  "Authorization" : "Bearer \(token)"]
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: header).responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response.result.value)
    }
}
```

With these functions I get the user details. But I'm wondering if I'm doing right. Is it the true way of doing this? If It is not, what is the true way. Thank you.

Comment: You're making a call to get a token and then include it in the headers, which is a fine way of doing it, but it's not OAuth2.

Comment: So what is it ?

Comment: It's a simple request to get a token from a server. OAuth is a single sing on mechanism where usually there is a third party which provides the login access for the users, thus only they can recognize users' credentials (e.g. user name and password). In your case you're sending the user name and password, which is far from OAuth

Comment: Also, please do not use http for the request!  Maybe it was just an oversight when sanitizing the URLs, but do not pass user credentials over http.

Comment: Let me explain what I'm trying to do. I have wrote a web service and the application communicate with web service. What is the safest way of doing this communication? For example users will login and the application will check it by using web service. How should I send user credentials?

Comment: I will use https @wottle